# Need to fix route table to allow local connections

Tags: vpn, ipconfig, routetable

I'm using a couple of different VPN products on Windows 7 which DO NOT allow for configuring of the split tunnel.  I know it's possible to modify the route table after the vpn is connected, but i haven't some trouble getting it to work given other examples on SO.  I would greatly appreciate any help.

I have done some obfuscation of the ips and domain-names, but otherwise it's exactly how i see it before i connect with the vpn.

```
>route print -4
===========================================================================
Interface List
 15...24 77 03 df b2 05 ......Microsoft Virtual WiFi Miniport Adapter
 14...24 77 03 df b2 04 ......Intel(R) Centrino(R) Ultimate-N 6300 AGN
 11...d4 be d9 84 6a 63 ......Intel(R) 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
 36...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
 37...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
 35...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft 6to4 Adapter #3
 52...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #3
 34...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
 39...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #8
===========================================================================

IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.0.1      192.168.0.5      2
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
      192.168.0.0    255.255.255.0         On-link       192.168.0.5    257
      192.168.0.5  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.0.5    257
    192.168.0.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.0.5    257
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link       192.168.0.5    257
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.0.5    257
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None


>ipconfig /all

Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : MYHOST
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . : some-domain.net
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : some-domain.net

Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection 2:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Virtual WiFi Miniport Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 24-77-03-DF-B2-05
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : domain.actdsltmp
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) Centrino(R) Ultimate-N 6300 AGN
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 24-77-03-DF-B2-04
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.5(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Tuesday, September 17, 2013 9:30:25 AM
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Wednesday, September 18, 2013 9:30:29 AM
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
                                       205.112.132.23
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : D4-BE-D9-84-6A-63
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter isatap.{B56AB647-7178-40B4-ABA4-C6DCF51D1134}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter isatap.{95E3911B-4B84-4447-9784-604AFA3ECF60}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #3
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 23:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : ::
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Disabled

Tunnel adapter isatap.domain.actdsltmp:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : domain.actdsltmp
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #8
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
```

And this is what it looks like post-connection

```
>route print -4
===========================================================================
Interface List
 57...02 05 85 7f eb 80 ......Juniper Networks Virtual Adapter
 15...24 77 03 df b2 05 ......Microsoft Virtual WiFi Miniport Adapter
 14...24 77 03 df b2 04 ......Intel(R) Centrino(R) Ultimate-N 6300 AGN
 11...d4 be d9 84 6a 63 ......Intel(R) 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
 36...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
 37...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
 35...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft 6to4 Adapter #3
 52...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #3
 34...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
 39...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #8
===========================================================================

IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0         On-link      62.120.66.47     11
     62.120.66.47  255.255.255.255         On-link      62.120.66.47    266
    62.129.16.182  255.255.255.255      192.168.0.1      192.168.0.5      2
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
      192.168.0.0    255.255.255.0         On-link      62.120.66.47     11
      192.168.0.5  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.0.5    257
    192.168.0.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      62.120.66.47    266
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link       192.168.0.5    257
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      62.120.66.47    266
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.0.5    257
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      62.120.66.47    266
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None


>ipconfig /all

Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : MYHOST
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . : SOMEDOMAIN.com
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : some.domain.names.com

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection* 31:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : some-domain.names.com
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Virtual Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 02-05-85-7F-EB-80
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 62.120.66.47(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.255
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 0.0.0.0
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 62.127.2.2
                                       62.100.146.1
   Primary WINS Server . . . . . . . : 62.100.145.1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection 2:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Virtual WiFi Miniport Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 24-77-03-DF-B2-05
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : domain.actdsltmp
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) Centrino(R) Ultimate-N 6300 AGN
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 24-77-03-DF-B2-04
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.5(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Tuesday, September 17, 2013 9:30:25 AM
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Wednesday, September 18, 2013 9:30:29 AM
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
                                       225.112.132.23
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : D4-BE-D9-84-6A-63
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter isatap.hyperras-ash-jpt.dupontnet.net:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : some-domain.net
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter isatap.{B56AB647-7178-40B4-ABA4-C6DCF51D1134}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter 6TO4 Adapter:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : some domain name
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft 6to4 Adapter #3
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 62.127.2.2
                                       62.100.146.1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Disabled

Tunnel adapter isatap.{95E3911B-4B84-4447-9784-604AFA3ECF60}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #3
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 23:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter isatap.domain.actdsltmp:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : domain.actdsltmp
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #8
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
```